# Migrating access db tables and data to SSMS, how can I verify that it migrated correctly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

So I've been tasked with migrating an access database to SSMS. I was wondering what ways I could audit and test my results. Verifying that everything moved correctly?

I've created a new DB on SSMS and imported the data from my access DB using the SSMS import tool and it generated a report giving me the results of the migration. Would analyzing the report be comprehensive enough to verify that it migrated correctly? Thank you

Comment: Start with row counts from every table? But honestly who know what you really mean by "everything moved correctly".

Comment: You'll have to do a little digging into this, but you may be able to use something like Red Gate SQL Data Compare to compare via SSMS.  Has a free, fully-functional trial download.  Worth a try.  https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/

Comment: You could compare results by using openrowset into a temp tables then using CHECKSUMAGG or EXCEPT to compare that the results are identical

Comment: Open the application--> change the connection to SQL server and test it. Many times there are issues with data types which you will have to figure out.